# Mount Java app inside cucumber rails app

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jar, cucumber

I have a rails app that talks to an api running on the same domain via ajax calls. I want to test this app using cucumber. The api is written in java and packaged as a jar. How can I mount the jar when using cucumber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it automatically but you can add Before hook into env.rb or put it into separate file and in this method you can load your java extension by issuing shell command, you can store process pid in variable and kill this process in After callbalk. You can configure Capybara to start server on specific port and I think you can tune your application to use specific port too.